# ld: undefined reference, but it should leave them unresolved

Tags: makefile, static-libraries, ld

I am unable to produce a library, which works with another library (SDL). I am using MinGW for make, and ld to link.  I am confused because a) it shouldn't be trying to link in these libraries, but do this later when someone links my library in as well; and b) even if I do link in the SDL libraries, it still can't find the SDL functions (`SDL_GetTicks`, `SDL_Delay`) it's looking form -- the errors are the same.  Also note that some of the missing items are from `std`.

Here are the errors.  As you can see, I'm trying various flags on ld to make it not try to resolve references, but w/o success yet.

```
C:\Users\...\mcve>make
g++ -c -c -I../../../external/SDL2/include -I../include -o mcve.o mcve.cpp
ld -G --unresolved-symbols=ignore-all --warn-unresolved-symbols  -o libmcve.a mcve.o    
C:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: mcve.o:mcve.cpp:(.text+0x8): undefined reference to `SDL_GetTicks'
C:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: mcve.o:mcve.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `SDL_GetTicks'
C:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: mcve.o:mcve.cpp:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `SDL_Delay'
C:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: mcve.o:mcve.cpp:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
C:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: mcve.o:mcve.cpp:(.text+0x67): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
C:\MinGW\bin\ld.exe: mcve.o:mcve.cpp:(.text+0x73): undefined reference to `atexit'
```

Here's my source file:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>         //If I take this out, I no longer get the 
                            //unresolved references to std::ios_base::Init::Init,
                            // std::ios_base::Init::~Init, and atexit

Uint32 time;    

void doSomething () 
{
  if (time > SDL_GetTicks ()) 
    SDL_Delay (time - SDL_GetTicks());
}
```

This is the Makefile.  If I uncomment the rest of the LDFLAGS and let the SDL libraries link in, it does not change the output.

```
CFLAGS  =-c -I../../../external/SDL2/include -I../include
LDFLAGS = --unresolved-symbols=ignore-all --warn-unresolved-symbols #-L. -lSDL2 -lSDL2_ttf -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_mixer 

# Files
SOURCE_FILES= mcve.cpp
OBJECT_FILES= mcve.o

libmcve.a: $(OBJECT_FILES)
    ld $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ -G

$(OBJECT_FILES): %.o: $(SOURCE_FILES)
    g++ -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

Comment: I don't know about MinGW, but usually you don't use the linker to create library (*.a) files. You would use an archiver such as `ar.exe`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to create the static library `libmcve.a` from the object file
`mcve.o` using the linker `ld`.

The linker cannot produce a static library. A [static library](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/static-libraries/info) is merely
an `ar` archive of object files that is produced by [`ar`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ar).

The recipe to create or update the static library in your makefile would be:

```
libmcve.a: $(OBJECT_FILES)
    rm -f $@    # Delete archive if already exists
    ar rcs $@ $^ # Recreate archive with contents $(OBJECT_FILES)
```

BTW, note that you are passing the `-c` option in your compilation commands
twice:

```
g++ -c -c -I../../../external/SDL2/include -I../include -o mcve.o mcve.cpp
```

That is because you have included it in your `CFLAGS` setting:

```
CFLAGS  =-c -I../../../external/SDL2/include -I../include
```

(where it should not be), and also in your compilation recipe:

```
g++ -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

(where it should be).